# MQ Connection does not disconnect

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, mq

We have implemented a JMSExceptionListener which on any connection exceptions get called. In this method we are closing the connection using connection.close(). When we do so we get the following exception

```
javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2003: failed to disconnect queue manager.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:374)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQSession.close(MQSession.java:1328)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:492)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.close(JmsConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.close(MQConnection.java:98)
```

Due to this the connection is in hung state and even if we do a new connection messages are going in uncomitted state. Is there a cleaner way to close the connection without getting this exception?

Will setting the setClientReconnectOptions help in this scenario? Please advise.

**Is there a way to do a health check of the connection object? How do I know if the connection object is stale?**

Comment: Can I suggest that you don't use PROVDER_VERSION 6 or shareconv=0 the channel... that ..wmq.v6.. is implying that the JMS client is running in it's migration mode. You might get better behaviour with provider version 7

Comment: sharecnv is already set to 0. But this error occurs after the connections are dropped by MQ server which is behind a firewall

Comment: Also in my pom I see the version of mqjms jar to be 7.0.1.5

Comment: Pratik, the suggestion from @Calanis was **not** to use sharecnv=0 and **not** to use PROVIDER_VERSION 6. Even though your jar is at version 7.0.1.5, you can still be using PROVIDER_VERSION 6 as you are. Set PROVIDER_VERSION to 7 instead.

Comment: I'd also suggest you upgrade to a newer Java client (mqjms jar). IBM released 7.0.1.5 in April 2011, nearly 4 years ago! 7.0.1.12 is the latest, and contains hundreds of fixes. The Java client is part of the MQC7 client support pack you can download here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24019253